# C# where to write safely in registry for all users

Tags: c#, registry

I 've a Windows Service which writes somes of this parameters in registry.
I want these parameters to be common to any users, means, whatever the Windows Service "RunAs".

Where you'd you recommand to write them?

I tried to write them in SOFTWARE\MyWindowsService\Server but I've permissions issues as you can see in this code.
For example here, I try to read and write in SOFTWARE\MyWindowsService\Server\Key1 and type of Key1 is string (REG_SZ)...

```
//Get current user for windows Service
_windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
MessageBox.Show("Try to change registry permissions for" + _windowsIdentity); //==> LocalSystem is my current account

//Get Main windows service registry
_WindowsServiceRegKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\THIS_WINDOWS_SERVICE_FOLDER\\SERVER", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs = _WindowsServiceRegKeys.GetAccessControl();

//Add new permissions
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(_windowsIdentity
                         , RegistryRights.FullControl
                         , InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit
                         , PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
_WindowsServiceRegKeys.SetAccessControl(rs);

//Try to read a var
object objRetRegistryKeyValue = _WindowsServiceRegKeys.GetValue("Key1"); //ERROR: object is null

_WindowsServiceRegKeys.SetValue("Key1", "Test", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Could you help me on this bug?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: How do you install the service ? Using an installer ? If you do can you add a step that would create the required registry key (folder) and change the permissions so that the account running the service can write in it (or Everybody depending on your service configuration)

Comment: Your assumption that this should be possible is just not accurate.  You have to write it to HKLM to let all users see the keys, UAC provides a basic guarantee that a non-elevated and non-privileged account (like System) cannot write such a key.  You of course cannot acquire UAC elevation in a service.  You must explicitly give the service account write access to the key, either by hand with Regedit or an installer.

Comment: @Sidewinder: thanks for your feedbacks! And yes, I use an Installer. That's exactly what I'm trying to do... I have almost found all pieces of code except how to get RunAs user of my windows Service...